# Padding in Array of Structures

Tags: c, embedded

I have a structure of varied elements,

```
struct 
{
  unsigned char aa;
  unsigned char bb[16];
  unsigned int cc;
  unsigned int dd;
  struct
  {
    unsigned char bit_0 :1;
    unsigned char bit_1 :1;
    unsigned char bit_2 :1;
    unsigned char dummy_bit :5;
  } Bits;
} Top_array[50],Top;
```

I know that for a single struct Top there will be padding between the elements. What happens when there is an array of structs Top_array. Will the padding still exist between Top_array[0] and Top_array[1]?

i.e. will sizeof(Top_array) be always 50 times sizeof(Top)?

Comment: The first question, is not the same as the "clarification" prefixed *"i.e."* (*that is to say*).  The answer to the first is "no" while the answer to the second is "yes".  Somewhat pedantic perhaps, but the first two answers started off "yes" - which initially confused me because I'd only got as far at the first question.

Answer (score 4):

> will sizeof(Top_array) be always 50 times sizeof(Top)?

Yes. There is possibly a padding at the end of the struct, so that when there is an array of it, the starting address of the struct and every member of it are still aligned.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly there is no padding *between* the elements of an array of structures; array elements are always contiguous - but there may be padding at the end of the structure to ensure array alignment, which has the same effect.

That is to say the padding is at the end of the structure and is part of the structure, rather than between elements.  If it were otherwise `sizeof(Top_array[0]) * 50` would not be equal to `sizeof(Top_array)`, which it must be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Types are padded so that, if you put them into arrays, each item in the array will be correctly aligned.

So, for example, the type:

```
struct {
    int myint;
    char mychar;
};
```

will have enough padding at the end to meet the alignment requirements of the `int`, if any.

Comment: So, if u create an array of such a struct, each array member will have a size of = ( int + char + padding) ?